# How to stop TailwindCSS from deleting unused styles

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css, production, tailwind-3

Okay, so I'm about to put my Laravel project in production. I tested everything on local host and it works perfectly using Tailwind 3. Yet, when I ran some PHP artisan commands to clear all cache and etc., `migrate:fresh` my database, and then ran `npm run dev`, I noticed that Tailwind removed the styles that I used in seeding blogs (I use seed to seed fake blog posts and view how they will look like).

For example I'm using the [Typography](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/typography-plugin) Tailwind plugin with the utility-class `prose` and so on. When I ran `migrate:fresh` and the fake blog post deleted from database, then cleared Laravel cache, and ran `npm run dev`, I noticed that all the `prose` styles are being removed from `app.css`. Of course I don't want that because this should be applied on each and every blog post that I will submit in production.

So how can I stop Tailwind from deleting these styles? I currently have all that I need and I don't want anything else removed.

**webpack.mix**

```js
    const mix = require("laravel-mix");

    /*
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     | Mix Asset Management
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |
     | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
     | for your Laravel applications. By default, we are compiling the CSS
     | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
     |
     */

    mix.js("resources/js/app.js", "public/js")
        .vue()
        .postCss("resources/css/app.css", "public/css", [
            require("postcss-import"),
            require("tailwindcss"),
            require("autoprefixer"),
        ]);
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```js
    const defaultTheme = require("tailwindcss/defaultTheme");

    module.exports = {
        darkMode: "class",
        content: [
            "./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php",
            "./storage/framework/views/*.php",
            "./resources/views/*.blade.php",
            "./resources/views/components/*.blade.php",
            "./resources/views/auth/*.blade.php",
            "./resources/views/layouts/*.blade.php",
            "./resources/js/components/categories/*.vue",
            "./resources/js/components/**/*.vue",
        ],

        theme: {
            screens: {
                xs: "364px",

                sm: "430px",

                sd: "644px",

                md: "768px",

                lg: "1024px",

                xl: "1155px",

                "2xl": "1280px",
            },
            extend: {
                fontFamily: {
                    sans: ["Nunito", ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
                },
                typography: ({ theme }) => ({
                    white: {
                        css: {
                            "--tw-prose-body": theme("colors.white"),
                            "--tw-prose-headings": theme("colors.blue[400]"),
                            "--tw-prose-lead": theme("colors.purple[700]"),
                            "--tw-prose-links": theme("colors.blue[800]"),
                            "--tw-prose-bold": theme("colors.blue[800]"),
                            "--tw-prose-counters": theme("colors.blue[900]"),
                            "--tw-prose-bullets": theme("colors.blue[900]"),
                            "--tw-prose-hr": theme("colors.blue[800]"),
                            "--tw-prose-quotes": theme("colors.blue[800]"),
                            "--tw-prose-quote-borders": theme("colors.blue[800]"),
                            "--tw-prose-captions": theme("colors.blue[800]"),
                            "--tw-prose-code": theme("colors.blue[800]"),
                            "--tw-prose-pre-code": theme("colors.blue[200]"),
                            "--tw-prose-pre-bg": theme("colors.gray[900]"),
                            "--tw-prose-th-borders": theme("colors.blue[300]"),
                            "--tw-prose-td-borders": theme("colors.blue[200]"),
                        },
                    },
                    black: {
                        css: {
                            "--tw-prose-body": theme("colors.black"),
                        },
                    },
                }),
            },
        },

        plugins: [
            require("@tailwindcss/forms"),
            require("@tailwindcss/typography"),
        ],
    };
```

Comment: It sounds like you don't have NPM running on production and it's not being transfered by Git? How did you setup Tailwind in your Mix?

Comment: I didn't deploy my website yet. I'm afraid that in production it will remove the styles like it happens when i run npm run dev on localserver. And I updated the question with laravel mix setup. Do i need to add something about Typography plugin in it?

Comment: As you can see in tailwind.config.js I'm adding forms and typography plugins from tailwind. do i need to do something in webpack.mix in regards of those plugins?

Comment: @N.Hamelink My last github commit included everything i needed in my project and tested on local server. Then i cleared all cache and deleted everything in database and ran npm run dev and here i noticed that it deletes unused styles such as Tailwind typography plugin (prose) styles which were used in one of the testing blog posts i created which i deleted from database as explained. so I'm afraid that this might happen when i deploy the website. I hope I made my issue clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tailwind will only include the classes that it finds by scanning the files specified in the `content` array in `tailwind.config.js`. If you want to include additional classes that are only in your dynamic content, you can safelist those classes in your config. For example:

```js
module.exports = {

  ...

  safelist: [
    'prose',
    'prose-xl',
  ],
  
  ...

}
```

See: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes